# Getting following error while displaying user information on a page in Angular and Ionic with Promise

Tags: angular, typescript, sqlite, ionic-framework, promise

In my app and on the `AccountSettingsPage` I am fetching user's data from `SQLite DB` and displaying it on an `Ionic` page. However, I am getting this error.

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/AccountSettingsPage.ngfactory.js:87:37)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (http://192.168.0.4:8100/build/vendor.js:15109:21)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://192.168.0.4:8100/build/vendor.js:14223:14)
    at callViewAction (http://192.168.0.4:8100/build/vendor.js:14569:21)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://192.168.0.4:8100/build/vendor.js:14501:13)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://192.168.0.4:8100/build/vendor.js:14224:5)
    at callViewAction (http://192.168.0.4:8100/build/vendor.js:14569:21)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (http://192.168.0.4:8100/build/vendor.js:14527:17)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://192.168.0.4:8100/build/vendor.js:14219:5)
    at callViewAction (http://192.168.0.4:8100/build/vendor.js:14569:21)
```

**account-settings.ts**

```
export class AccountSettingsPage {

  currentUser: User;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, private userProvider: UserProvider) {
    this.getCurrentUserDetails("ab@cd.com");
  }

  getCurrentUserDetails(email: string) {
    this.userProvider.getUserByEmail(email)
      .then((currentUser: User) => {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
        console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(currentUser));
      })
      .catch(e => console.error(JSON.stringify(e)));
  }

}
```

**user.ts (UserProvider)**

```
getUserByEmail(email: string): Promise<User> {
    return this.databaseProvider.getDatabase().then(database => {
      return database.executeSql(SQL_SELECT_USER_BY_EMAIL, [email])
        .then((data) => {
          let user: User;
          //loop through all the records and populate the user object. Should be only 1
          for (let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            user = {
              id: data.rows.item(i).id,
              name: data.rows.item(i).name,
              email: data.rows.item(i).email,
              password: data.rows.item(i).password,
              confirmPassword: data.rows.item(i).password,
              phone: data.rows.item(i).phone,
              street1: data.rows.item(i).street1,
              street2: data.rows.item(i).street2,
              city: data.rows.item(i).city,
              state: data.rows.item(i).state,
              zip: data.rows.item(i).zip,
              active: data.rows.item(i).active
            };
          }
          //return the populated user object back
          return user;
        });

    });
  }
```

**account-settings.html (Page)**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Account Settings</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-label>Name: {{currentUser.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Email: {{currentUser.email}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Password: {{"*****"}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Phone: {{currentUser.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Street 1: {{currentUser.street1}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Street 2: {{currentUser.street1}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>City: {{currentUser.city}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>State: {{currentUser.state}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Zip: {{currentUser.zip}}</ion-label>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Do you really mean `data.rows.item(i)`? Given that you loop through `data.rows` It would make more sense to use `data.rows[i]` but then it would make even more sense not to loop at all and just use the properties of `data.rows[0]` (if it exists; if not then throw).

Comment: I am still new to JS and mobile development world. Will try out your suggestions @Roamer-1888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) to only display the user data when `currentUser` has successfully loaded. As `currentUser` is not initialized with default values for all these properties you are rendering and loaded asynchronously, you can use this structural directive to avoid attempting to access these properties of an undefined object until is has successfully loaded/resolved:

```
<ion-content *ngIf=“currentUser” padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-label>Name: {{currentUser.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Email: {{currentUser.email}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Password: {{"*****"}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Phone: {{currentUser.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Street 1: {{currentUser.street1}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Street 2: {{currentUser.street1}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>City: {{currentUser.city}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>State: {{currentUser.state}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Zip: {{currentUser.zip}}</ion-label>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
</ion-content>
```

You can expand on this concept by using an `else` statement with `*ngIf` to perhaps show a loading message or similar while the data is loading:

```
<ion-content *ngIf=“currentUser; else loadingCurrentUser” padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-label>Name: {{currentUser.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Email: {{currentUser.email}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Password: {{"*****"}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Phone: {{currentUser.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Street 1: {{currentUser.street1}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Street 2: {{currentUser.street1}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>City: {{currentUser.city}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>State: {{currentUser.state}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Zip: {{currentUser.zip}}</ion-label>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
</ion-content>

<ng-template #loadingCurrentUser>
  Loading...
</ng-template>
```

Lastly consider executing this call in the Angular lifecycle hook [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) instead of the constructor, this is the ideal place of initialization tasks such as this database call:

```
export class AccountSettingsPage implements OnInit {
  currentUser: User;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, private userProvider: UserProvider) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCurrentUserDetails("ab@cd.com");
  }

  getCurrentUserDetails(email: string) {
    this.userProvider.getUserByEmail(email)
      .then((currentUser: User) => {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
        console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(currentUser));
      })
      .catch(e => console.error(JSON.stringify(e)));
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 2):

On the creation of your view, your `currentUser` in your controller is `undefined`, til it is fetched from the database.

You should add an *ngIf directive onto your HTML to prevent the display if `currentUser` is undefined.

```
<ion-content *ngIf="currentUser" padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-label>Name: {{currentUser.name}}</ion-label>
    <!-- ... -->
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
</ion-content>
```

Then update the **UserProdiver** to actually return a value from the promise :

```
getUserByEmail(email: string): Promise<User> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.databaseProvider.getDatabase().then(database => {
      database.executeSql(SQL_SELECT_USER_BY_EMAIL, [email])
        .then((data) => {
          let user: User;
          //loop through all the records and populate the user object. Should be only 1
          for (let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            user = {
              id: data.rows.item(i).id,
              name: data.rows.item(i).name,
              email: data.rows.item(i).email,
              password: data.rows.item(i).password,
              confirmPassword: data.rows.item(i).password,
              phone: data.rows.item(i).phone,
              street1: data.rows.item(i).street1,
              street2: data.rows.item(i).street2,
              city: data.rows.item(i).city,
              state: data.rows.item(i).state,
              zip: data.rows.item(i).zip,
              active: data.rows.item(i).active
            };
          }
          //return the populated user object back
          return resolve(user);
        });
    });
  });
}
```